# How to clear cache in Controller CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, browser-cache

I am working a properties website where user creates the listing and later to save it, we ask him to connect via Facebook. Currently it is working nice but, when I create another property (say a User did not login) and later I just go back to that page of creating property and later connect via facebook then.. it does log the user in but, does not create the property..
I tried various things and later I figured out that once I clear browser cache, it is creating the properties.

So, my question is, how to clear cache in browser using CakePHP 2.x?

Also, I have tried:

Pure HTML :

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

however, it did not help. Is there a way to do it via CakePHP itself? or is it Facebook thing which needs to be addressed?

Please advise.

PS: `clearCache() does not work` I don't know why.

Comment: clearCache affects the server-side cache, so it does nothing on the client. Having the client-side cache behave as one wants to is more a matter of sending the right HTTP response headers, and additionally handling client requests that check if a resource is still valid appropriately. But I don’t get from your question, where the _actual_ problem lies – I can’t see, what kind of “properties” you are trying to create and how caching affects that, and how the FB login comes into play.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CBroe . I understand that but, I am finding it not so wise to show 2 controller and associated model files because, as I said, once I clear the client side cache and again click, it does the work! So, dropping down to clearer question : How to clear cache on the browser - the cake style (preferred).

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

Comment: well, that was helpful, only if I had time to go more about it :( Can you point anything specific?... Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot clear a browser's cache unless you are actually the one using the browser.  (eg. `File->Options->Clear Cache`)

What you're talking about is just telling the browser to not cache YOUR page in the first place - which it appears you already know how to do.

But once it's cached, it's cached by THEIR browser, not YOUR code.  It would be a security issue and easily abusable among other things to allow you to delete the users cache.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CakeResponse::disableCache()`

```
Example:

 <?php
        public function search() {
        // do something.
            $this->response->disableCache();
       }
```

Comment: Doesn't help . Actually it is disabling the Cake Cache on response. Cache is coming from FB...

Comment: OP: "So, my question is, how to clear cache in browser using CakePHP 2.x?" - and the answer is to not use cache in the first place?  Either this answer is wrong or the question isn't actually the question.